# Maintaining user permission on user seesion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis

I am developing MVC website. In my website all the pages are based on user permission( based on theirs role). Like some of the user will have permission for all pages and some of all only permitted for fewer pages. 
In the menu itself if the user not having permission we need to display some tool-tip like, there is no permission.  For every request we are hitting DB and getting permission details. Instead of hitting DB for every request, shall we maintain the permission information for that user in server session?

Comment: What is your authentication mechanism? Is it asp.net identity framework?

Comment: I am authenticating users using asp.net mvc **form authentication**

Comment: I am not using asp.net membership. I have created custom tables for storing user information (username and password) and user permission.